# Checking whether element exists in a Vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector and it is going to hold 10 objects maximum. When I create the vector I believe it creates 10 "blank" objects of the class it will hold. Therefore I have a problem because my code relies on checking that a vector element is null and obviously it is never null.

How can I check whether a vector object contains an element I inserted, or one of the default constructor "blank" objects upon initialisation?

Is there a technique round this?

(I need to check for null because I am writing a recursive algorithm and the termination point, when the recursive function returns is when an object in the vector is null)

Comment: Whether it contains "blank" objects or not (actually they are default-constructed instances) depends on whether you used `resize(10)` or `reserve(10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of a class cannot be null.  Only a pointer.

You do, however, have size() that you can use.

```
typedef stdd::vector<SomeClass> vec;
//define some vec, v
for (vec::size_type i = 0, s = vec.size(); i < s; ++i) {
    //do something with v[i]
}
```

With a recursive function you could use this idea by passing along a maximum index.

```
void recursiveFunc(vec& v, vec::size_type s);
```

Then when checking your condition to recurse, you would need to check "am I at the end of the vector?"

Alternatively, instead of working on indexes, you could use iterators:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void recursiveFunc(Iterator begin, const Iterator& end);
```

If done correctly (and if possible in your situation), this could decouple your manipulation from being aware of the underlying data being stored in a vector.

The loop to go over the vector would then look like:

```
while (begin != end) {
    //do something with *begin
    ++begin;
}
```

Comment: So if I created a Vector with an initial blocksize of 10, if I didnt insert anything into the Vector the size would be 0? (and I presume capacity 10)

Comment: @user997112: Yes. And it must be contiguous.

Comment: @Corbin: Not so -- a `vector` does *not* insert default-constructed items into the unused space it has allocated. It normally works by allocating raw memory, then using placement new to construct items in that memory when needed, but the memory where you haven't inserted anything is just raw memory, not objects.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah very true.  Should have thought that through more.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` only inserts "real" objects. It (at least normally) allocates raw memory, and uses placement new to construct objects in that memory as needed. The only objects it'll contain will be the ones you put there.

Of course, if you *want* to, you can create a vector containing a number of copies of an object you pass to the constructor. Likewise, when you `resize` a vector, you pass an object it'll copy into the new locations if you're making it larger.

Neither of those is really the norm though. In a typical case, you'll just create a `vector`, which will start out containing 0 objects. You'll use `push_back` to add objects to the `vector`. When you search through the `vector`, the only objects there will be the ones you put there with `push_back`, and you don't need to worry about the possibility of it containing any other objects.

If you just want to check whether the `vector` is empty, you can just use:

```
if (your_vector.empty())
```

...which will (obviously enough) return `true` if it's empty, and `false` if it contains at least one object.

Answer (score 0):

As @Corbin mentioned, size() will return the number of elements in the vector. It is guaranteed not to have any holes in between(contiguous), so you assured vector[vector.size()] is empty.

Comment: Its not so much that, I just want to be able to tell if the whole vector is empty and full of non-real objects